# Finding corresponding row value of a data frame using an other data frame

Tags: r

Is it possible to find corresponding rows of one data frame in an other data frame. 
Using R commands? 
After that store the result in an other data  frame.

Example:

```
     data1 = airquality[1:14,]
     data2 = data.frame(index=data1$Ozone[6:14])
```

I want to have in an other data frame the date corrresponding the same rows of this 2 data frame. I consider the Ozone value of data1 like index.

So what i want to get finally is somethings like this in data3:

```
     index  Month Day
     28         5   6
     23         5   7
     19         5   8
      8         5   9
     NA         5  10
      7         5  11
     16         5  12
     11         5  13
     14         5  14
```

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted. Please show some example dataset and your expected result.

Comment: You might be looking for `merge` but it's really not clear right now.

Comment: The Ozone column in airquality has duplicated entries which makes it not very well suited to serve as index. Example: row 7 of your data1 is a 7, but a 7 is also in row 76 and 147 of the original data. So how do you know in the example, what rows of data1 you want to add to data2?

Comment: I just put an example of the result I want.But in my own data the index corrrespond to my rownames we can't meet duplicated values.

Comment: Take a look at `?merge`

Comment: I merge the 2 dataframe how can I filter the corresponding data without taking rows 1 to 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `%in%` operator:

```
data3 <- data1[data1$Ozone %in% data2$index, c("Ozone", "Month", "Day")]
data3

   Ozone Month Day
5     NA     5   5
6     28     5   6
7     23     5   7
8     19     5   8
9      8     5   9
10    NA     5  10
11     7     5  11
12    16     5  12
13    11     5  13
14    14     5  14
```

You have NAs in your index example. R will pick all NAs in the resulting data.frame. Unless you want to pick all of them, avoid using them in indexes.

If you wanted to use row names, you could do something like this:

```
data1[!rownames(data1) %in% 1:5, c("Ozone", "Month", "Day")]

   Ozone Month Day
6     28     5   6
7     23     5   7
8     19     5   8
9      8     5   9
10    NA     5  10
11     7     5  11
12    16     5  12
13    11     5  13
14    14     5  14
```

See [here](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html) for further information about subsetting. Also [this site](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html) is helpful.